# Как заполнить граф рандомными значениями

Tags: c

Мне нужно реализовать проблему Комивояжера с помощью графов. И этот граф должен быть заполнен с помощью рандома. Но, я не могу понять как это осуществить.

```
struct Node
{
    int dest[1000];
    int name;
    int surname;
    int age;
    int weight[1000];

    struct Node* next;
};

struct Graph
{
    struct Node* head[1000];
};

struct Edge
{
    int src, weight;
};


struct Graph* createGraph(int choice);

int main()
{
    int choice, i, c, l = 0;
    printf( "Enter how many people u want to have:");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);

    c = choice / 2;

    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(choice);
}


struct Graph* createGraph(int choice)
{
    int i, j, dest[10000], k, c = choice / 2;
    int tmp, b = choice / 2;

    struct Graph* gg = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));

    for (i = 0; i < choice; i++)
    {
        gg->head[i] = NULL;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < choice; i++) {

        struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

        int src = i;
        if (i < choice / 2) {


            for (j = 0; j < choice / 2; j++)
            {
                dest[j] = b;
                b++;
            }

            b = choice / 2;


            for (int z = 0; z < choice / 2; z++)
            {
                k = rand() % b + 0;
                tmp = dest[z];
                dest[z] = dest[k];
                dest[k] = tmp;
            }

            for (int z = 0; z < choice / 2; z++)
            {

                newNode->dest[z] = dest[z];
                newNode->weight[z] = rand() % 100 + 1;

            }

        }
        else
        {

            for (i = 0; i < choice / 2; i++)
            {
                dest[c] = i;
                c++;
            }


            for (int z = 0; z < choice / 2; z++)
            {
                k = rand() % b + 0;
                tmp = dest[z];
                dest[z] = dest[k];
                dest[k] = tmp;

            }

            for (int z = 0; z < choice / 2; z++)
            {

                newNode->dest[z] = dest[z];
                newNode->weight[z] = rand() % 100 + 1;


            }

            newNode->age = rand() % 73 + 18;
            newNode->name = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
            newNode->surname = 'A' + (rand() % 26);

            newNode->next = NULL;

            gg->head[src];



        }
    }

    return (gg);
}
```

Comment: *я не могу понять как это осуществить* - это не вопрос, это - утверждение. Вопрос то в чём заключается?  И то же тогда программу писал?